# using 720p, 1080p as enum in swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to use 720p, 1080p as enums in swift. However, I can't. I got an error saying "Expected a digit after integer literal prefix"

```
enum ASResolution {
    case lowResolution
    case 720p
    case 1080p
    caee highResolution
}
```

What should I do?

I revised my code as below:

```
enum ASResolution:Int {
    case low = 1
    case HD = 720
    case fullHD = 1080
    case high = 2000
}
```

Comment: HDready and fullHD should do the work

Comment: I don t think you can use digits in the name of your enums.

Comment: But 720p is not a digits, it just starts with digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much you can do if you want to keep those names.
An enum case is an *identifier*, and as you can see from the [Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID412) there are restrictions for what you can use as the first character.

So, pretty much as you can't start a variable name with a digit (they are identifiers as well), you can't start an enum case with a digit.

The few options you have are:

- prefix the identifier with a permitted character (such as the underscore)
- completely change the identifier, using words (`sevenTwoZeroP` and `oneZeroEightZeroP`) or synonyms (`HDReady` and `FullHD`)

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will try that.